# Can I set the AnyConnect group policy from users source IP?

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

Is it possible to configure a Group Policy to be used based on the source IP of the AnyConnect user?

I want users connecting from a specific location (IP address) to get a specific Group policy. When those same users travel to another network, they would get a different Group Policy.

- ASA is 9.12
- AnyConnect is 4.8

Comment: Can't check right now but wouldn't this be possible with a DAP policy?

Comment: @hertitu I don't see that as a criteria to filter against in DAP (unless I just missed it).

Comment: @JesseP. It's been a (very) long time since I worked with DAP but IIRC ip address is one of the attributes provided by HostScan (VPN Posture).

Comment: @hertitu HostScan is also a paid feature of AnyConnect that requires additional licensing and such.

Comment: @8None1 If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, please mark my answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: @hertitu HostScan gives the LAN address. I'm looking for the public source IP the ASA would see from a connecting client.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen a way to do that natively (in the ASAs themselves) but, if your AnyConnect setup uses RADIUS for authenticating users, you could assign group policies based on a condition statement that looks for CallingStationID (the IP address they're coming from) and matches the users that way.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't remember a way to do it without an AAA back end either (all my deployments for years have used AAA), which is why I didn't throw in an answer. Can do this and a whole lot more with an AAA back end.

Comment: @YLearn Yeah. Same. I only use local auth when I'm first building things out.

Comment: @JesseP. We don't use RADIUS, but it's an interesting reason to possibly try it. Would the CallingStationID be the public source or would it be what the calling host thinks it's IP is (meaning internal LAN it's on)?

Comment: @8None1 What do you use for user authentication? It would be whatever the IP address is that the request to connect comes from.  If the user is connecting from the public Internet, it would be their public IP address.

Comment: @8None1 Are you still in need of help with this, or are you giving the RADIUS option a shot?